# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Race object

Tags: python, django

I know it seems like a stupid quotation but I truly cant find an answer.
I dont know where my problom is in my code, the only thing I do know is that I ran the site, and when i insert an object of type Race, I couldnt run the site anymore, i checked the database and it was added as it should. when I checked the error in the internet i couldnt find an answer because all of the answers dont include an answer about a Foregin key.
Here is the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()

  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\final_proj\DDD\DDD\urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path('characters/',include('characters.urls',namespace='characters')),
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\final_proj\DDD\characters\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\final_proj\DDD\characters\views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from characters.forms import RaceForm,RolesForm,CharacterForm
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\final_proj\DDD\characters\forms.py", line 36, in <module>
    class CharacterForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 253, in __new__
    fields = fields_for_model(
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 175, in fields_for_model
    formfield = f.formfield(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 989, in formfield
    return super().formfield(**{
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 419, in formfield
    return super().formfield(**defaults)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 910, in formfield
    defaults['choices'] = self.get_choices(include_blank=include_blank)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 852, in get_choices
    blank_defined = any(choice in ('', None) for choice, _ in self.flatchoices)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 882, in _get_flatchoices
    for choice, value in self.choices:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Race object
```

**Views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404,redirect,get_list_or_404
from characters.models import Character,Role,Race
from django.utils import timezone
from characters.forms import RaceForm,RolesForm,CharacterForm
from django.urls import reverse,reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,DetailView,CreateView,UpdateView,DeleteView)
from . import forms
   class CreateCharacterView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'characters/character_detail.html'

    form_class = CharacterForm

    model = Character

class CreateRaceView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'characters/race_detail.html'

    form_class = RaceForm

    model = Race

class CreateRoleView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'characters/roles_detail.html'

    form_class = RolesForm

    model = Role

class CharacterListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'characters/character_list.html'

    model = Character

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Character.objects.order_by('name')

class RacesListView(ListView):
    model = Race

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Race.objects.order_by('name')

class RolesListView(ListView):
    model = Role

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Role.objects.order_by('name')

class CharacterDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Character

class RacesDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Race

class RoleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Role


class CharacterUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'characters/character_detail.html'

    form_class = CharacterForm

    model = Character

class RaceUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'characters/race_detail.html'

    form_class = RaceForm

    model = Race

class RoleUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'characters/role_detail.html'

    form_class = RolesForm

    model = Role

class CharacterDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
    model = Character
    success_url = reverse_lazy('characters:character_list')

class RaceDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
    model = Race
    success_url = reverse_lazy('characters:race_list')

class RoleDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
    model = Role
    success_url = reverse_lazy('characters:role_list')
```

**forms.py**:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Role,Race,Character


class RaceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Race
        fields=('name','attack','deffence','intelligence','agility','wisdom','charisma')

        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
            'attack': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
            'deffence': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
            'intelligence': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
            'agility': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
            'wisdom': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
            'charisma': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
        }

class RolesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields=('name','attack','deffence','intelligence','agility','wisdom','charisma')

        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
            'attack': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
            'deffence': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
            'intelligence': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
            'agility': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
            'wisdom': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
            'charisma': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
        }

class CharacterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Character
        fields=('name','description','race','role')

        widgets={
            'name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'editable medium-editor-textarea postcontent'}),
        }

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['race'].queryset = Race.objects.all()
            self.field['role'].queryset=Role.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your indentation is wrong on `CharacterForm` and your `__init__` is in `class Meta`.

Comment: it was a problem, but wasnt the problem i still get the error